# Autorest generates Client Sdk that needs a beta package

Tags: azure, .net-core, nuget, azure-functions, autorest

I use [Autorest](https://github.com/Azure/autorest) to generate a Client Sdk for an *Azure Function*.

After that the Client Sdk should be packed and pushed to our nuGet feed.

These steps will all be done with a `yaml` pipeline for *Azure DevOps*.

**This works really good for the last months. But recently Autorest has stopped working as usual.**

Unfortunately autorest generates a project file that needs a **beta** nuGet package.

```xml
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.AutoRest.CSharp" Version="3.0.0-beta.20210205.2" />
```

Of course, nuGet pack is not able to pack a project with beta or pre-release dependencies.

- Does anyone have the same issue with autorest?
- Can i configure autorest, not to use beta packages?

The generated project file looks like this:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <TreatWarningsAsErrors>true</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
    <Nullable>annotations</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <LangVersion>8.0</LangVersion>
    <IncludeGeneratorSharedCode>true</IncludeGeneratorSharedCode>
      <RestoreAdditionalProjectSources>https://azuresdkartifacts.blob.core.windows.net/azure-sdk-tools/index.json</RestoreAdditionalProjectSources>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.AutoRest.CSharp" Version="3.0.0-beta.20210205.2" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Core" Version="1.6.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

The Pipeline that generates, packs and push the Client Sdk looks like that:

```yaml
steps: 
  - powershell: 'npm install -g autorest@latest'
    displayName: "Install AutoRest"
  - task: AzurePowerShell@4
    displayName: "Download Swagger"
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: ${{parameters.subscription}}
      scriptType: 'InlineScript'
      azurePowerShellVersion: 'LatestVersion'
      inline: |
        $context = New-AzApiManagementContext -ResourceGroupName "${{parameters.apimResourceGroup}}" -ServiceName "${{parameters.apim}}"  
        Export-AzApiManagementApi -Context $context -ApiId "$(appName)-development" -SpecificationFormat OpenApi -SaveAs "$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\definition-$(version).yaml"
  - powershell: 'autorest --verbose --v3 --csharp --add-credentials --input-file="$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\definition-$(version).yaml" --output-folder="$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)\Api\src\ClientSdk" --namespace="ClientSdk" --override-client-name="Client"'
    displayName: 'Run AutoRest'    
  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: "Pack Projects"
    inputs:
      command: "pack"
      arguments: "--configuration $(buildConfiguration) --include-symbols"
      packagesToPack: "**/ClientSdk.csproj"
      versioningScheme: "off"
      verbosityPack: "Normal"
  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    inputs:
      command: 'push'
      packagesToPush: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/**/*.nupkg;!$(Pipeline.Workspace)/**/*.symbols.nupkg'
      nuGetFeedType: 'internal'
      publishVstsFeed: ${{parameters.nugetfeed}}
```

The nuGet pack task failes with this error

`1>C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.102\Sdks\NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack\build\NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack.targets(207,5): error NU5104: A stable release of a package should not have a prerelease dependency. Either modify the version spec of dependency "Microsoft.Azure.AutoRest.CSharp [3.0.0-beta.20210205.2, )" or update the version field in the nuspec.`

Answer (score 0):

Using a pre-release package in a release package is unstable and dangerous. This error is there to prevent this from happening. There are a couple options you can employ:

**Mark your package as pre-release**

Assuming your project is still in development and needs to utilize this latest dependency that's still in development, simply mark your package as in development as well. From the [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/prerelease-packages):

> If your project uses PackageReference: include the semantic version
> suffix in the .csproj file's PackageVersion element:
>
> ```
> <PropertyGroup>
>     <PackageVersion>1.0.1-alpha</PackageVersion>
> </PropertyGroup>
> ```
>
> If your project has a packages.config file: include the semantic
> version suffix in the .nuspec file's version element:
>
> ```
> <version>1.0.1-alpha</version>
> ```

**Use the last stable build**

Fall back to the last version of your dependencies that use release packages. This is generally safer, as in-development dependencies may introduce serious issues that are yet unknown. If the project developers believed their project to be safe for production use they would mark it as such.

Comment: [Autorest](https://github.com/Azure/autorest) is a tool to generate a Sdk based on OpenApi / Swagger. I don't want to use beta or pre-Release packages, but autorest generates a project, that needs this beta package.

Comment: Your question states that it was previously working. So use the version of Autorest that was previously not using beta packages. As a general rule, it's good to specify specific versions of all your dependencies, rather than the latest by default, so that breaking changes like this one do not occur.

Comment: adding a specific version works: `autorest --version=3.0.6336 ...`